# How to correctly do array request in volley

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I'm trying to do get request and get array in json but i'm having error like this:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

here's my request code:

```
private fun getStudents(endLink: String) {
    val request = JSONObject()
    val studentLink = "https://192.168.1.1/getStudents.php?idEntity="
    val linkFull = studentLink.plus(endLink)
    val jsArrayRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, linkFull, request, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
        val builder = GsonBuilder()
        val gson = builder.create()
        val student =
            gson.fromJson<Students>(it.toString(), students::class.java!!)
        studentResponse = studentResponse
        //updateInfo()
    }, Response.ErrorListener {
        Log.d("ERRORKA", it.message)
        Toast.makeText(
            this.context,
            it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    })

    MySingleTon.getInstance(this.context!!).addToRequestQue(jsArrayRequest)
}
```

also my data models:

```
class StudentResponse {
var groupNumber: String = ""
var students: List<Students>? = null
}
```

here's 2nd:

```
class Students {
val id: Int = 0
val firstName: String? = ""
val lastName: String? = ""
val middleName: String? = ""
val email: String? = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing `jsonArrayRequest`, you can see the object you are creating is of `JsonObjectRequest`. Do like below.

```
    // Method: POST
    val mDataArray = JSONArray(); // This should be JSONArray object
    val mRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,"YOUR API URL", mDataArray,{
        //Response listener
    },{
        //Error listener
    })

    // Method: GET
    val mRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,"YOUR API URL", null,{
        //Response listener
    },{
        //Error listener
    })
```